# Angularjs timing with a filter and an $http service

Tags: angularjs

When my app loads i register a filter and a service with angular.
But the filter is trying to execute before the service comes back with the data so my items collection is barking in the filter. 
I had a fiddle for it but i don't know if you can use $http in a fiddle because it is an external resource. Here is what i have [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vbahole22/GU7tL/)
Sorry that it doesn't actually work. its been through alot.
I think my issue is timing. I need the filter to wait for the http response or just not 'enforce' itself.

The error i get now is 'items is undefined' cause that is where the filter is being applied.
I did have this working before i tried to mash the http call into a service. But i feel like that is the angular way and i "just want to be in compliance".

When my controller fires it makes the call to fetch data:

```
eventApi.async().then(function () {
    $scope.eventCollection = eventApi.data();
});
```

but before it gets back the filter is applied in the html:

```
 <tr ng:repeat="event in events  | myEventFilter:ddlFilter |
       orderBy:sort.column:sort.descending">
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vbahole22/GU7tL/)

Comment: also, it does work after all the dust settles. it just throws a bunch of errors initially about the filter not having any items to deal with

Comment: Instead of $http, use $timeout (with a timeout of, say, 2 seconds) to simulate a delay in jsfiddle.  Inside the timeout callback, hard-code your data as if it came back from the server.  Post that working fiddle and we'll have a look (because your fiddle has more than just $http issues).

Comment: Here's a fork of the fiddle that fixes a couple of the other issues: (1) eventApi wasn't being injected into the controller and (2) the main app module wasn't depending on the chartApp module. http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/WwR4U/

Comment: Here is it is. http://jsfiddle.net/Vbahole22/kJR9e/5/

Comment: In there i have a live switch - false we get the static event set in the controller. true we get the timeout service call

Comment: VBAHole, just FYI... when you add a comment and you would like SO to notify someone about that comment, put e.g., @Mark in the comment.  Then that person will get notified.  I didn't know you updated your fiddle.  But Brandon took good care of you already :)  Note that SO will always notify the person associated with the question or comment where the comment is made.  E.g., you'll get notified about this comment even though I didn't use the @ notation with your username.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a fork of your updated fiddle that fixes a couple missed dependencies (`eventApi` not injected into the controller, `$timeout` not injected into the `eventApi` service). My comments will be based on this code: http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/zww7e/1/

This fiddle successfully gets us to the issue you posted about: "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" in your filter. In general, filters should be able to handle null/undefined values by default. I would simply modify the filter to read something like this:

```javascript
return function (items, eventFilterType) {
  var arrayToReturn = [];
  if (items === undefined) return arrayToReturn;
  // ...
}
```

That should take care of your root problem; the fiddle now runs without errors, although it doesn't appear to work properly; as far as I can tell, it's because you're setting `$scope.eventCollection` instead of `$scope.events` in the `if (live)` section of your controller. Making this change causes data to actually show up in the view.

However, you may be interested in another property of Angular: when you use a promise built with `$q`, you can bind the view directly to the promise, and the view will *treat* it as though you bound it to the *resolved value* of the promise. So, for example, you can do the following:

```javascript
// in the service
$timeout(function () {
  deffered.resolve(fakeEvents); // <-- resolve with the data
}, 2000);
return deffered.promise;

// in the controller
if (live) {
  $scope.events = eventApi.async();
}
```

Here's an updated version of the fiddle that demonstrates this technique: http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/zww7e/2/

**[Update]**

As pointed out by Jeff in the comments, Angular is deprecating automatic promise unwrapping; you can [see the commit here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/5dc35b527b3c99f6544b8cb52e93c6510d3ac577), but here is the message:

> **fix($parse): deprecate promise unwrapping and make it an opt-in**
>
> This commit disables promise unwrapping and adds
>   $parseProvider.unwrapPromises() getter/setter api that allows
>   developers to turn the feature back on if needed. Promise unwrapping
>   support will be removed from Angular in the future and this setting
>   only allows for enabling it during transitional period.
>
> If the unwrapping is enabled, Angular will log a warning about each
>   expression that unwraps a promise (to reduce the noise, each
>   expression is logged only onces). To disable this logging use
>   `$parseProvider.logPromiseWarnings(false)`.
>
> Previously promises found anywhere in the expression during expression
>   evaluation would evaluate to undefined while unresolved and to the
>   fulfillment value if fulfilled.
>
> This is a feature that didn't prove to be wildly useful or popular,
>   primarily because of the dichotomy between data access in templates
>   (accessed as raw values) and controller code (accessed as promises).
>
> In most code we ended up resolving promises manually in controllers or
>   automatically via routing and unifying the model access in this way.
>
> Other downsides of automatic promise unwrapping:
>
> - when building components it's often desirable to receive the   raw promises
> - adds complexity and slows down expression evaluation
> - makes expression code pre-generation unattractive due to the   amount of code that needs to be generated
> - makes IDE auto-completion and tool support hard
> - adds too much magic
>
> BREAKING CHANGE: $parse and templates in general will no longer
>   automatically unwrap promises. This feature has been deprecated and if
>   absolutely needed, it can be reenabled during transitional period via
>   `$parseProvider.unwrapPromises(true)` api.

Comment: unbelievable! thank you so much. angular has been a lot of fun when it works and alot of heartburn when it doesn't. but the community is incredible and everyone has been very helpful. i guess that, in and of itself, is a direct reflection of that fact that the framework works.

Comment: Happy to have helped! I've had similar experiences, but once it clicks it's great!

Comment: I used the above technique when parsing date values:
`if (value === undefined)
    return new Date();
return new Date(parseInt(value.substr(6)));`

Comment: Automatic promise unwrapping was actually just removed from angular core.

Comment: @JeffHubbard Thanks, that's actually very interesting to note even outside the scope of this question. I've updated the answer.